# Node positioning relative to 2 other nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm wanting to align/position a node relative to 2 others. Basically I'd like everything to be in rows and columns (whose is determined by the largest member). In this specific instance, I'd like node `j` to be centered on the intersection of the red and blue lines in the picture below. This would cause the 2 decision diamonds to be evenly spaced like `f` and `g`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{state}   = [ rounded rectangle, draw, 
                        text centered, 
                        minimum height=3em 
                      ]
\tikzstyle{test}    = [ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 0pt,
                        text width = 7em,
                        text centered
                      ]
\tikzstyle{action}  = [ rectangle, draw,
                        text width=8em,
                        inner sep = 5pt, 
                        minimum height=5em
                      ]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.25em, align = flush center, font = \small]
    % Place nodes
    \node [test] (f) {fLorem ipsum dolor sit amet};
    \node [test, right=of f] (g) {gLorem ipsum dolor};
    \node [test, below=of f] (h) {hLorem ipsum dolo};
    \node [action, below=of h] (i) {iLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.};
    \node [action, right=of i, fill=gray] (j) {jLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.};
    \node [test, below=of i] (l) {lLorem ipsum dolor};
    \node [test, below=of j, fill=gray] (m) {mLorem ipsum dolor};

    \draw [red] (g) -- +(0,-10);
    \draw [blue] (i) -- +(10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: alignment]

I've read some promising things about `chains` but think it might be over kill for my use.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are two easy approaches to this. If you really just want to place one node *"at the intersection of the red and blue lines"*, you can easily use the `perpendicular` coordinate system (pgfmanual 2.10 page 130), which is designed for exactly this use. This is shown in the first `tikzpicture`.

However, as you also requested *"everything to be in rows and columns (whose [size] is determined by the largest member)"*, there is a far better and far more sensible way to achieve the desired effect. Simply use the TikZ `\matrix` command, which is equivalent to `\node[matrix]` (pgfmanual 2.10 page 201 and 375). With matrices, you can easily align things in rows and columns without having to worry about things like column types (was with `tabular`).

Here's an example image of the two techniques applied, followed by the slightly-more-minimal example that produced the image.

[image: Output of example document]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] at (0,0) (left node) {Left Node};
    \node[draw] at (3,2) (top node) {Top Node};


    \node[draw] at (left node -| top node) {Node at intersection};
    %\node[draw,circle] at (top node |- left node) {Another node at the same position};

    \draw [red] (top node) -- +(0,-3);
    \draw [blue] (left node) -- +(6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm] (m) {
                                         & \node[draw] (top node) {Top Node};\\
    \node[draw] (left node) {Left Node}; & \node[draw] {Intersection Node};\\
    };
    \draw [red] (top node) -- +(0,-3);
    \draw [blue] (left node) -- +(6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can further use the `matrix of nodes` key to avoid explicitly typing `\node...` for each cell. The options the nodes can be given through `nodes={draw}` key. Also they are directly named as `(m-row no-col no)` hence you can skip the names.

Comment: @percusse: Yes, but doesn't that make adding options to  individual cell-nodes more difficult? In the OP's MWE it looks like he'll have very diverse styles for each node, which is why I used explicit `\node`s with explicit styles. You're probably right though that I should at least mention that in my answer.

Comment: You are right. Maybe I was carried away a little there but you can overwrite the individual options via `&|[draw,blue]| node text` per entry which is slightly less work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `let` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{state}   = [ rounded rectangle, draw, 
                        text centered, 
                        minimum height=3em 
                      ]
\tikzstyle{test}    = [ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 0pt,
                        text width = 7em,
                        text centered
                      ]
\tikzstyle{action}  = [ rectangle, draw,
                        text width=8em,
                        inner sep = 5pt, 
                        minimum height=5em
                      ]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.25em, align = flush center, font = \small]
    % Place nodes
    \node [test] (f) {fLorem ipsum dolor sit amet};
    \node [test, right=of f] (g) {gLorem ipsum dolor};
    \node [test, below=of f] (h) {hLorem ipsum dolo};
    \node [action, below=of h] (i) {iLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.};
    \path let \p1=(g), \p2=(i) in node[action, fill=gray] (j) at (\x1,\y2)   {jLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.};
    \node [test, below=of i] (l) {lLorem ipsum dolor};
    \node [test, below=of j, fill=gray] (m) {mLorem ipsum dolor};

    \draw [red] (g) -- +(0,-10);
    \draw [blue] (i) -- +(10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]