# How to position tikz node relative to 2 other nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Suppose, I have this structure:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes, positioning}
\begin{document}
\def\len{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = \len, auto]
\tikzset{
    line/.style = {draw},
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=2em},
}
\node [block] (1-1) {1-1};
\node [block, below = of 1-1] (1-2) {1-2};
\path [line] (1-1) -- (1-2);
\node [block, below right = of 1-2] (2-1) {2-1};
\path [line] (1-2) -| (2-1);
\node [block, right = of 2-1] (3-1) {3-1};
\node [block, dotted] at(3-1|-1-2) (3-2) {3-1};
\path [line] (1-1) -| (3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I position node 3-1 to the right of node 2-1 and on the same level with 1-2, using calc library? I drew the desired position, using dotted borders.

Please, don't suggest to use matrix.

### Update

1 approach is to use `above right = of 2-1`. It would work for this test case, but if node 1-2 is tall, it wouldn't position 1-3 vertically to the  centre of it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes, positioning}
\begin{document}
\def\len{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = \len, auto]
\tikzset{
    line/.style = {draw},
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=2em},
}
\node [block] (1-1) {1-1};
\node [block, below = of 1-1, text width = 1cm] (1-2) {text, text, text (!): $\frac{1}{2}$};
\path [line] (1-1) -- (1-2);
\node [block, below right = of 1-2] (2-1) {2-1};
\path [line] (1-2) -| (2-1);
\node [block, above right = of 2-1] (3-1) {3-1};
\path [line] (1-1) -| (3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Gives this:

[image]

### Update 2

@Bordaigorl suggested to use `right = 2 of 1-2`. But if 2-1 is wide, it will visually overlap with 3-1:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes, positioning}
\begin{document}
\def\len{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = \len, auto]
\tikzset{
    line/.style = {draw},
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=2em},
}
\node [block] (1-1) {1-1};
\node [block, below = of 1-1, text width = 1cm] (1-2) {text, text, text (!): $\frac{1}{2}$};
\path [line] (1-1) -- (1-2);
\node [block, below right = of 1-2] (2-1) {2-2-2-2-2};
\path [line] (1-2) -| (2-1);
\node [block, right = 2 of 1-2] (3-1) {3-1};
\path [line] (1-1) -| (3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Possible solution

I used an extra \coordinate node to the right of 2-1. Is it possible to solve the problem without it?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes, positioning}
\begin{document}
\def\len{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = \len, auto]
\tikzset{
    line/.style = {draw},
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=2em},
}
\node [block] (1-1) {1-1};
\node [block, below = of 1-1, text width = 1cm] (1-2) {text, text, text (!): $\frac{1}{2}$};
\path [line] (1-1) -- (1-2);
\node [block, below right = of 1-2] (2-1) {2-2-2-2-2};
\path [line] (1-2) -| (2-1);
\node [coordinate, right = of 2-1.east] (3-1) {};
\node [block] at(3-1|-1-2) (3-2) {3-1};
\path [line] (1-1) -| (3-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seriously, you should use a `matrix` of nodes... :p

Comment: @Jubobs I looked at Gonzalo Medinas answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70336/node-positioning-relative-to-2-other-nodes, but couldn't make it work for my case. Is it possible to use calc?

Comment: is there a specific reason you want a solution with `calc`? Or you meant `positioning`?

Comment: You can use `above right=of 2-1`? You can use `\coordinate (@) at (1-2-|2-1.east);` and then `right=of @`. Many possibilities. Also compare `node distance=1cm` with `node distance=1cm and 1cm` for diagonal placements.

Comment: @Bordaigorl I think, it would require using both positioning and calc.

Comment: My solution below uses just `positioning`, is that what you are after?

Comment: @user4035 Actually I proposed `right=2 of 1-2` which work as you'd expect...

Comment: I must say that `matrix` seems the best solution...

Comment: @Bordaigorl yeah, I thought, it might be possible to do it via calc somehow.

Comment: @user4035 have you considered using the `on grid` option? I would need few changes but I think that's what you need...I may post a new answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use `right=of 2-1 |- 1-2` (without `calc` library):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\def\len{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = \len, auto]
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=2em},
}
\node [block] (1-1) {1-1};
\node [block, below = of 1-1] (1-2) {1-2};
\node [block, below right = of 1-2] (2-1) {2-1};
\node [block,right=of 2-1 |- 1-2] (3-1) {3-1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Paul, how could i add a node above 2-1 and right of 1-2 i.e. pseudo-code `\node [block,above=of 2-1 and right of 1-2] (4-1) {4-1}` ; `\node [block,above=of 2-1 |- 1-2] (4-1) {4-1};` positions the node too high / not to the right of `1-2`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @user2957945 Try `\node[block,at={(2-1 |- 1-2)}] (4-1) {4-1};`

Comment: Great, thanks Paul; appreciate your help

Answer (score 4):

You can use `positioning` for that by asking it to place `3-1` "two to the right" of `1-2`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = \len, auto]
    \tikzset{
        line/.style = {draw},
        block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=2em},
    }
    \node [block] (1-1) {1-1};
    \node [block, below = of 1-1] (1-2) {1-2};
    \path [line] (1-1) -- (1-2);
    \node [block, below right = of 1-2] (2-1) {2-1};
    \path [line] (1-2) -| (2-1);
    \node [block, right =2 of 1-2] (3-1) {3-1};
    % \node [block, dotted] at(3-1|-1-2) (3-2) {3-1};
    \path [line] (1-1) -| (3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However this does not scale well if the nodes have dissimilar sizes.

To accommodate all the constraints one can use the `on grid` option that, when using `positioning` keys, instructs TikZ to use centers of nodes as reference points for positioning:

```
\begin{document}
\def\len{2cm}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\len, y=\len, on grid]
        \tikzset{
            line/.style = {draw},
            block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=2em},
        }
        \node [block] (1-1) {1-1};
        \node [block, below =1 of 1-1, text width = 1cm] (1-2) {text, text, text (!): $\frac{1}{2}$};
        \path [line] (1-1) -- (1-2);
        \node [block, below right =1 of 1-2] (2-1) {2-2-2-2};
        \path [line] (1-2) -| (2-1);
        \node [block, right =1.5 of 1-2] (3-1) {3-1};
        \path [line] (1-1) -| (3-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A few changes are needed:

1. here the distances must be changes since now they stand for distances between centres, not borders (hence `\def\len{2cm}`)
2. we use explicit dimensionless relative coordinates in the positioning keys to be able to scale if necessary using the `x` and `y` keys

Now you can add content to the nodes as you wish but they remain in their relative positions, as now they are relative to the centres.
If later on the spacing is not enough you can redefine `\len` (or `x` and `y` individually) to space the nodes out.

Comment: I tried it. 1 min, I'll explain, why I didn't like this approach

Comment: question updated

Comment: My solution *does* center `3-1` and `1-2` vertically...

Comment: I'll show another potential bug in your solution. Another 5 mins

Comment: @user4035 ok =) it seems you haven't explained all your constraints in the question...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I made everything equal, while in reality they can be unequal. Question updated.

Comment: @user4035 I edited the answer using the `on grid` key, I guess that's at least closer to your original intention (an yet it does not use `calc`)