# tikz: how to place a node aligned with two other nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Having seen this answer [How to position tikz node relative to 2 other nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144472/how-to-position-tikz-node-relative-to-2-other-nodes), I thought I'd try something similar, but must be missing a step.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {A};
    \node [right = of A] (B) {B};
    \node [right = of B] (C) {C};
    \node [below = of A] (D) {D};
    \node [right = of D -| C] (E) {E};
    \node [below = of C |- D] (F) {F};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to position node E to the right of node D and under node C, but I seem to get one but not the other. Why?

[image]

Comment: Using `below = of <locn>` means the node will be placed *below* the `<locn>`. In this case you want the node placed *at the specific location*, so you use `\node at (D -| C) (E) {E};`.

Comment: Ah! That make sense. So what I asked for was a node that was to the right of a node that was in line with node D (horizontally) and in line with C (vertically.) I'd accept this as an answer, but it's a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The perpendicular coordinate system helps. The node is placed on the base line of node `D` and in the horizontal middle of node `C`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {A};
    \node [right = of A] (B) {B};
    \node [right = of B] (C) {C};
    \node [below = of A] (D) {D};
    \node [anchor=base] (E) at (C |- D.base) {E};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Vertical centering is even easier:

```
\node (E) at (C |- D) {E};
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the two answers above, both Paul Gessler and 
Heiko Oberdiek deserve credit, this is the solution.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {A};
    \node [right = of A] (B) {B};
    \node [right = of B] (C) {C};
    \node [below = of A] (D) {D};
    \node  at (D -| C) (E) {E};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```