# Relative positioning with tikz and let syntax results in slightly incorrect (y-axis) position

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to set the position of the `b` node based on the `x` position of one, and the `y` position of another node.

I use the `let` function, as I learned from another [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70336/node-positioning-relative-to-2-other-nodes).

In my code this somehow results in a slightly incorrect position where the node is positioned slightly lower than expected, resulting in a minor but noticeable gap.

Here you can see that the `b` node and its label is below the `y` position of node `w1`:
[image]

I know this is a very minor problem, but I would like to understand it.
What causes the gap?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,3d,calc,fit,shadows,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning,chains,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [start chain=2,node distance=13mm, label distance=3mm]
\tikzstyle{init} = [
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep=2pt,
    font=\Huge,
    join = by -latex
]

\tikzstyle{squa} = [
    draw,
    inner sep=2pt,
    font=\Large,
    join = by -latex
]

\node[on chain=2] (x2) at (0,0) {$x_2$};
\node[on chain=2,join=by o-] {$w_2$};
\node[on chain=2,init] (sigma) {$\displaystyle\Sigma$};
\node[on chain=2,label=above:{\parbox{2cm}{\centering Activation \\ function}}] (phi) {$\phi(...)$};
\node[on chain=2,label=above:Output, join=by -latex] (y) {$y$};
\begin{scope}[start chain=1]
    \node[on chain=1,label=above:Inputs] at (0,1.5cm) (x1) {$x_1$};
    \node[on chain=1,label=above:Weights, join=by o-] (w1) {$w_1$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[start chain=4]
    \node[on chain=4] at (0,-1.5cm) (xn) {$x_{n}$};
    \node[on chain=4,join=by o-] (wn) {$w_{n}$};
\end{scope}

\path let \p1=(sigma), \p2=(w1) in node[label=above:Bias] (b) at (\x1, \y2) {$b$};

\draw[-latex] (w1) -- (sigma);
\draw[-latex] (wn) -- (sigma);
\draw[o-latex] (b) -- (sigma);
\path (x2) -- (xn) node [font=\large, midway, sloped] {$\dots$};

\draw[-latex] (sigma) -- (phi) node[above, midway] (net) {\textit{net}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Structure of an Artificial Neuron}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is explained and solved in the tutorial in the pgfmanual v3.1.4 on pages 70-71. What you seeing here are the effects of `p` and `g` "going below the baseline" and `b` being higher than `x` and `w`. You can solve the issue by giving the nodes some fixed `text height`s and `text depth`s. (I also used the opportunity to get rid of the deprecated `\tikzstyle` and removed libraries which are not used here. The red lines are only to guide the eye.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=2,node distance=13mm, label
 distance=3mm,fw/.style={text depth=0.25ex,text height=1.5ex},
 every label/.append style={fw},
 init/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=2pt, font=\Huge, join= by -latex},
 squa/.style={draw, inner sep=2pt, font=\Large, join = by -latex}]

\node[on chain=2,fw] (x2) at (0,0) {$x_2$};
\node[on chain=2,join=by o-,fw] {$w_2$};
\node[on chain=2,init] (sigma) {$\displaystyle\Sigma$};
\node[on chain=2,label=above:{\parbox{2cm}{\centering Activation \\ function}}]
(phi) {$\phi(\dots)$};
\node[on chain=2,label=above:Output, join=by -latex] (y) {$y$};
\begin{scope}[start chain=1]
    \node[on chain=1,label=above:Inputs,fw] at (0,1.5cm) (x1) {$x_1$};
    \node[on chain=1,label=above:Weights, join=by o-,fw] (w1) {$w_1$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[start chain=4]
    \node[on chain=4] at (0,-1.5cm) (xn) {$x_{n}$};
    \node[on chain=4,join=by o-] (wn) {$w_{n}$};
\end{scope}

\path let \p1=(sigma), \p2=(w1) in node[label={[name=Bias]above:Bias},fw] (b) at (\x1, \y2) {$b$};

\draw[-latex] (w1) -- (sigma);
\draw[-latex] (wn) -- (sigma);
\draw[o-latex] (b) -- (sigma);
\path (x2) -- (xn) node [font=\large, midway, sloped] {$\dots$};

\draw[-latex] (sigma) -- (phi) node[above, midway] (net) {\textit{net}};
\begin{scope}[overlay,red,thin] % only for illustration
 \draw (b.base-|b.south east) -- ++ (-4.5,0);
 \draw (Bias.base-|Bias.south east) -- ++ (-5,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Structure of an Artificial Neuron.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm.